# If $f(x)\to \infty$ then $1/f(x)\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ then $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{f(x)}=0.$

$\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall E\in \mathbb{R}$ $\exists M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $x>M$ we have $|f(x)|>E$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given then for $E=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ $\exists M$ such that for any $x>M$ we have $\left|\frac{1}{f(x)}\right|<\epsilon$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, maybe include more steps to be clear,

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Then, since $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}=\infty$, for $E=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, $\exists M$ such that for any $x>M$ we have $\midf(x)\mid<E=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\implies \mid\frac{1}{f(x)\mid<\varepsilon$

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that $x\rightarrow\infty$ means $|x|\rightarrow+\infty$ according to the definition in your proof.

Therefore, I think you'd better change $x>M$ to $|x|>M$ in your proof.

Comment: Yes you are right! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but why in many books they does not write $|x|>M$? They write $x>M$.

Comment: This depends on the meaning of your notation. As I mentioned, I read from your proof that $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$ means $|f(x)|\rightarrow+\infty$, not $f(x)\rightarrow+\infty$.